# Change sorting in report services

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I have a report which is populated from a stored procedure. I want to change it so it will be sorted from a column other than the one is sorted in stored procedure. I dont want to change the stored procedure. So I clicked on "Tablix Properties" -> "Sorting" and I added the column that I want to sort the grid by. But it didn't worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the row group sorting property to see if there is a sorting field or expression. In case it exists, it overrides the sorting of the tablix property.

To check the row group property, right click the row group and from the menu choose Row Group --> Group Properties. From the Group Properties windows, choose the sorting option

[image]

Comment: can you tell me how I can check the row group sorting property?

Comment: there is no sorting field or expression. I added there the same field but not success again

Comment: Could be a sorting expression existing in a row group

Comment: ok solved it! there was another group with the same columns and I had to change it there. thank you!